# Rendering a control generates security exception in .Net 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, .net-4.0, blogengine.net

I am having a problem with code that worked fine in .NET 2.0 but is giving this error under .Net 4.

> Build (web): Inheritance security
>   rules violated while overriding
>   member:
>   'Controls.RelatedPosts.RenderControl(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)'.
>   Security accessibility of the
>   overriding method must match the
>   security accessibility of the method
>   being overriden.

This is in DotNetBlogEngine.  There were several other security demands in the code that .NET 4.0 doesn't seem to like.  I followed some of the advice I found on blogs (and here) and got rid of all the other errors.  But this one still eludes me.

The Main BlogEngine core `dll` is not set for security demands any longer and is compiled for .NET 4.0 as well.

This error is in the website side attempting to use the `dll`.  There are controls that call a `RenderControl` method taking an `HtmlTextWriter`.  Apparently the text writer now has some soft of security attributes set on it.

Each of the controls implements a custom interface ( `public interface ICustomFilter` ), there are no security permissions present or demands.  The site is running full trust on my local dev machine.

Update:

I have tried the various settings under the security namespace in .NET 4 I [read about here](http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2010/04/23/what-is-new-in-asp-net-4-0-code-access-security.aspx).  I know this is a code access security change, but I don't understand the why behind it not working (or the error message).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set this attribute
[assembly: SecurityRules(SecurityRuleSet.Level1)]

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233102%28VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: Yea, did that.  It didn't work.  I also tried level 2, and tried doing the same in the website instead of the dll.  None of the combinations I tried worked.  Thanks.

Comment: why did this answer get the 'check' if it did not work? how did you get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I needed to do to run under .net 4.0 was to add a reference to System.Web.ApplicationServices to the Core project.